# 2 namespace with same class name - is it need to use "use" alias to call first namespace?

Tags: php, oop

From my below code, I try to call the sayHi method, in class Cat with `namespace foo;`
but it not work, I have to use "use" to change name to call it;

```
    <?php

    namespace foo;

    class Cat
    {
        public static function sayHi()
        {
            echo "Meow";
        }
    }

    namespace bar;

    class Cat
    {
        public static function sayHi()
        {
            echo "Hello";
        }
    }


    foo\Cat::sayHi();  //try to use backslash path  but Fatal error: Class 'bar\foo\Cat' not found

?>
```

if I use `Cat::sayHi();`  it always call the method from namespace bar that I don't want.  so **Question: Are there any method that solve this problem  without use  '`use`' alias?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare a namespace, your code operates within that namespace until you declare another, or until the end of the file. You're doing this:

```
namespace foo;
class Cat {}
namespace bar;
class Cat {}
// here you are in namespace bar
foo\Cat::sayHi();
```

Since you're already in the bar namespace, and your namespace reference doesn't anchor the root namespace, this final line is interpreted as:

```
\bar\foo\Cat::sayHi();
```

Simply anchor to the root:

```
\foo\Cat::sayHi();
```

Or put your call to `foo\Cat::sayHi();` in another file.